# Why the icon on the button looks so big?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I'm trying to give an icon to the button but it looks like this!

[image]

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Button"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_facebook"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm tried to find a related issue on the internet but unfortunately can't find anything related to this issue or I did not search enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `app:iconSize="24dp"` property to your button in your xml. You can change 24dp whatever size you want. One thing to mention, this will work only with MAterialButton.

Comment: But why in this [video](https://youtu.be/tOwZTXPOmJU?t=225) does not set `app:iconSize` and the button looks well without that property

Comment: Well, because he is using system vector images and probably he selected that icon in an approprite size like 18 or 24 dp in the Android Studio. And probably you are not using a vector but a png or jpeg image. You can achive it resizing your image to an approprite icon size if you don't preffer to use the iconSize property.